# Get date from two different timestamp formats in one pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have a pyspark dataframe that has a timestamp field. But it contains two types of timestamp format (both are strings).

```
   +----------------------+
    | timestamp           |
    +---------------------+
    | 06-06-2019,17:15:46|
    +---------------------+
    |2020-01-01T06:07:22.000Z
```

How can I create another "date"column in the same pyspark dataframe that captures only the date based on the timestamp field ?
The ideal result looks like this

```
+----------+---------------------+
|      date|timestamp            |
+----------+----------------------+
|2019-06-06| 06-06-2019,17:15:46 |
+----------+----------------------+
|2020-01-01|2020-01-01T06:07:22.000Z|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need to define a function for this case and use the function in **dataframe**.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col, to_date

def dynamic_date(col, frmts=("MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd")):
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, i) for i in frmts])

df.show(10,False)
#+------------------------+
#|timestamp               |
#+------------------------+
#|06-06-2019,17:15:46     |
#|2020-01-01T06:07:22.000Z|
#+------------------------+

df.withColumn("dd",dynamic_date(col("timestamp"))).show(10,False)
#+------------------------+----------+
#|timestamp               |dd        |
#+------------------------+----------+
#|06-06-2019,17:15:46     |2019-06-06|
#|2020-01-01T06:07:22.000Z|2020-01-01|
#+------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hello,

I am new to python can you please write 

coalesce(*[to_timestamp(col, i) for i in frmts] in a non pythonic way??